# Python 3.7 UltimateBruteforcer

Tags: python, performance, python-3.x, multiprocessing

So I made a bruteforce program for sha-X hashes and MD5 using wordlists in Python.
I know Python is probably one of the worst languages for this, but it's only for learning purposes.
I think this was a good way for me to learn optimization.
I am still a beginner in coding, so my code might have some things that aren't the best :)
I am searching for some help on optimizing the program and also learn about multiprocessing and if there is a way I can add it to my program :)

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# coding:utf-8
#
# Author:                Thewizy
# Date:                  19-02-2019
# Purpose:               Find password from hashes using wordlists
# Prerequisites:         A big wordlist and of course hashes
#
# And now - the fun part :>

import os
import datetime
import argparse
import itertools
from urllib.request import hashlib
from progress.bar import Bar


def main():
    normal()


def countlines_hashfile():
    with open(h) as myfile:
        count = sum(1 for line in myfile)
        return count


def countlines_wordfile():
    with open(w) as myfile:
        count2 = sum(1 for line in myfile)
        return count2


def wordlist_options():
    path = "tmp"

    if not os.path.exists(path):
        os.makedirs(path)
    with open(w) as f:
        with open(os.path.join(path, "tmp.txt"), 'w') as temp_file:
            for line in f:
                if args.replace:
                    line = replace(line)
                if args.repeat:
                    line = line + line
                if args.uppercase:
                    line = line.upper()
                if args.title:
                    line = line.title()
                temp_file.write(line)

            temp_file_name = temp_file.name
    return temp_file_name


def hashmethod():

    hash_file = open(h).read()

    for hash in hash_file.split("\n"):
        # find type of hash are the hashes in the hash file with the length of it else raise an error message
        lenght = len(hash)
        if lenght == 32:     # MD5
            hashmethod_list.append(1)

        elif lenght == 40:   # sha1
            hashmethod_list.append(2)

        elif lenght == 56:  # sha224
            hashmethod_list.append(3)

        elif lenght == 64:   # sha256
            hashmethod_list.append(4)

        elif lenght == 96:   # sha284
            hashmethod_list.append(5)

        elif lenght == 128:  # sha512
            hashmethod_list.append(6)

        else:
            hashmethod_list.append(0)
            print(" /!\ Invalid Hash: " + hash + " /!\ ")

        hash_list.append(hash)


def wordhasher(word,hashline):

    if hashmethod_list[hashline] == 1:
        hashedguess = hashlib.md5(bytes(word, "utf-8")).hexdigest()
    elif hashmethod_list[hashline] == 2:
        hashedguess = hashlib.sha1(bytes(word, "utf-8")).hexdigest()
    elif hashmethod_list[hashline] == 3:
        hashedguess = hashlib.sha224(bytes(word, "utf-8")).hexdigest()
    elif hashmethod_list[hashline] == 4:
        hashedguess = hashlib.sha256(bytes(word, "utf-8")).hexdigest()
    elif hashmethod_list[hashline] == 5:
        hashedguess = hashlib.sha384(bytes(word, "utf-8")).hexdigest()
    elif hashmethod_list[hashline] == 6:
        hashedguess = hashlib.sha512(bytes(word, "utf-8")).hexdigest()
    else:
        hashedguess = "ERROR"
        parser.error(" /!\ Invalid Hash Line: " + str(hashline + 1) + " /!\ ")  # should QUIT doesnt work now

    return hashedguess


def normal():
    hashline = 0
    i = 0
    word_list = open(w).read()
    bar = Bar("<<PASSWORD TESTED>>", max=lines_wordfile)

    for word in word_list.split("\n"):

        if args.prog:
            bar.next()
        savedword = word

        while True:

            # Reset the hash line to line 0 when all hashes have been checked and print the guessed password
            if hashline >= lines_hashfile:
                hashline = 0
                if args.show:
                    print(word)
                if args.numbers:
                    l = len(digits_list)
                    if i - 1 >= int(l -1):
                        i = 0
                        break
                    else:
                        nd = digits_list[i]
                        i += 1
                        if args.front:
                            word = str(nd) + savedword
                        elif args.extremity:
                            word = str(nd) + savedword + str(nd)
                        else:
                            word = savedword + str(nd)

                else:
                    break

            # Read the next hash in the list
            hash = hash_list[hashline]

            # Check if the word hashed is equal to the hash in file

            if wordhasher(word,hashline) == hash:
                result = word + " Line " + str(hashline + 1) + ": " + hash
                result_list.append(result)

            hashline += 1
    if args.prog:
        bar.finish()
    readresult()


def replace(word):
    word = word.replace("e", "3").replace("a", "4").replace("o", "0")
    return word


def dates():

    dates = []
    dates_day = ["1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","01","02","03","04","05","06","07","08","09","10","11","12","13",
                 "14","15","16","17","18","19","20","21","22","23","24","25","26","27","28","29","30","31"]
    dates_month = ["1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","01","02","03","04","05","06","07","08","09","10","11","12"]

    for days, month in itertools.product(dates_day, dates_month):
        dates.append(days+month)

    for years in range(1875,2020):
        dates.append(years)
    return dates


def numbers(number_digits):
    i = 0
    digits_list = []

    while i <= int(number_digits):
        n = str(i)
        digits_list.append(n)
        i += 1

    print(digits_list)
    return digits_list


def readresult():

    end_time = datetime.datetime.now()
    print("Time taken: -{" + str(end_time - start_time) + "}-")

    if not result_list:
        print("No Password Found")
        print(result_list)
    else:
        for a in result_list:
            print(a)
            if args.save:
                s = open(save, "a")
                s.write(str(result_list))


if __name__ == '__main__':

    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description="Ultimate Sha1/256/512 and MD5 hashes Bruteforcer with dictionaries",
                                     prog="UltimateBrutforcer",
                                     usage="%(prog)s.py <your_wordlist.txt> <your_hashlist.txt> -option1 etc...")

    parser.add_argument("wordlist", help="The wordlist you wish to use.(Example: wordlist.txt)", type=str)
    parser.add_argument("hashlist", help="The hashlist you wish to find the password.(Example: hashlist.txt)", type=str)
    parser.add_argument("-n", "--numbers",default=False, dest="numbers", action="store_true",
                        help="Put numbers at the end of each word")
    parser.add_argument("--common", default=False, dest="common", action="store_true",
                        help="Use most common number used in password only")
    parser.add_argument("--dates", default=False, dest="dates", action="store_true",
                        help="Use all possible dates")
    parser.add_argument("--fr", default=False, dest="front", action="store_true",
                        help="Change the numbers to be at the beggining of the word")
    parser.add_argument("--ex", default=False, dest="extremity", action="store_true",
                        help="Change the numbers to be at the extremity of the word")
    parser.add_argument("-r", "--replace", default=False, dest="replace", action="store_true",
                        help="Replace every E by 3, every A by 4, and every = O by 0(zéro)")
    parser.add_argument("-p", "--repeat", default=False, dest="repeat", action="store_true",
                        help="repeat the word two times")
    parser.add_argument("-u", "--upper", default=False, dest="uppercase", action="store_true",
                        help="Change the word in uppercase")
    parser.add_argument("-t", "--title", default=False, dest="title", action="store_true",
                        help="Write the word as a title, ex: title word -> Title Word")
    parser.add_argument("-s", "--save", default=False, dest="save", action="store_true",
                        help="Save the results in a text file.")
    parser.add_argument("-pr", "--progression", default=False, dest="prog", action="store_true",
                        help="Show the progression of the scan with a progression bar"
                             "might be useful to explain how Bruteforce works to some people")
    parser.add_argument("-sh", "--show", default=False, dest="show", action="store_true",
                        help="Show the password tested(/!\TAKES A LOT MORE TIME/!\)"
                             "might be useful to explain how Bruteforce works to some people")

    args = parser.parse_args()
    # All errors about options:
    if args.front and not args.numbers:
        parser.error('-n is required when --front is set.')
    if args.extremity and not args.numbers:
        parser.error('-n is required when --front is set.')
    if args.common and not args.numbers:
        parser.error('-n is required when --common or -c is set.')
    if args.extremity and args. front:
        parser.error('you cannot put those two options to -n')
    if args.common and args.dates:
        parser.error('you cannot put those two options to -n.')
    if args.show and args.prog:
        parser.error('you cannot put those two options together.')

    # global variables:
    w = args.wordlist
    h = args.hashlist
    lines_hashfile = countlines_hashfile()
    lines_wordfile = countlines_wordfile()
    result_list = []
    hashmethod_list = []
    hash_list = []

    if args.replace or args.repeat or args.uppercase or args.title:
        w = wordlist_options()

    if args.numbers:
        digits_list = []
        if args.common:
            digits_list = ["1", "12", "123", "1234", "12345", "123456", "1234567", "12345678", "123456789", "00", "01",
                           "10", "11", "13", "19","22", "23", "42", "69", "77", "99", "314", "666", "777", "111",
                           "100", "200"]
        elif args.dates:

            digits_list = dates()

        else:
            while True:
                number_digits = input("How many numbers do you want to put"
                                      "(/!\max is 6 numbers!\)")
                if number_digits.isdigit() and int(number_digits) <= 6:
                    number_digits = "9" * int(number_digits)
                    digits_list = numbers(number_digits)
                    number_digits = ""
                    break
                else:
                    parser.error('A number lower or equal to 6 is required for the lenght of the numbers')

    if args.save:
        run = True
        while run:
            save = input("How do you want to name the save file?")
            if save != "":
                save = save+".txt"
                break

    print("\n" + "-Found [" + str(lines_hashfile) + "] hashes in hashlist " +
          "\n" + "-Found [" + str(lines_wordfile) + "] words in wordlist")

    hashmethod()
    input("\n"+"Press <ENTER> to start")
    start_time = datetime.datetime.now()  # Save the time the program started
    main()
    print("Scan finished")
    try:
        os.remove("tmp")
    except PermissionError:
        print("PermissionError: tmp file couldn't be removed (need administrator permissions)")
```

You can also find the code with wordlists and hashlist for test here:
https://github.com/Thewizy/UltimateBruteforcer

Comment: Can you add the actual code? or reasonable chunk of it? (Similar to your other questions) :)

Comment: I know my questions are similar :) but this time the code is not as small :)

Comment: I did this but i had to add spaces myself the indentation won't work I guess I'm going to do it with my spacebar

Comment: sorry I didn't mean it is similar to other questions. I meant add code as you did in other questions :)  This looks nice now that code is added.

Comment: Oh yes misunderstood :)

Comment: Unless the misspelling is an intentional skirting of keyword restrictions, you might want to change `lenght` to something else.

Comment: @LSpice No keyword issues. But write an answer.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Just a few quick comments

- You can use a dictionary as mapping file

  First you check the length of the bytes and use an `temp` variable `1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6` to know which hashing algo to use

  > ```
  > lenght = len(hash)
  > if lenght == 32:     # MD5
  >     hashmethod_list.append(1)
  > ...
  > if hashmethod_list[hashline] == 1:
  >     hashedguess = hashlib.md5(bytes(word, "utf-8")).hexdigest()
  > ```

  Thi can be simplified using a dictionary that maps the length of the hash to the correct function

  ```
  BYTELEN_TO_HASH = {
      32 : hashlib.md5,
      40 : hashlib.sha1,
      56 : hashlib.sha224,
      64 : hashlib.sha256,
      96 : hashlib.sha384,
      128 : hashlib.sha512
  }

  def brute_password(hash_line):
      hash_func = BYTELEN_TO_HASH.get(len(hash_line), None)
      if hash_func is None:
          return f'Incorrect hash: {hash_line} with length {len(hash_line)}'


      for word in read_wordlist():
          if hash_func(bytes(word, "utf-8")).hexdigest() == hash_line:
              return word

      return 'No matching password found'
  ```

  This is alot shorter and removes those `magic` numbers
- Creating a new wordlist for each optional argument will cost alot of IO operations

  Instead you could read the file and alter the word after you read it from the wordlist

  We could possibly? make another optional function dictionary

  ```
  OPTIONS = {
      'U', str.upper
      ...
  }

  optional = OPTIONS.get(optional, lambda x: x)
  for word in read_wordlist():
      word = optional(word)
  ```

Comment: Ok thanks a lot I didn't know i could use dictionaries to change a command based on a value

Comment: About the wordlist I actually had ealier version of the program where the program had no tmp file and was reading the file and altering them as they come but I've see a really small performance gain by applying the options first

Comment: But since you have to wait for the file to be ready it's actually a lost of time :/ so I might removed the tmp file

Comment: You don;t need to alter the file in place. Just read the wordlist as usual and alter the word's value

Comment: You are right it's easier and faster

Comment: I've expanded on the second point a bit. Have to go I hope you receive some more good answers :)

Comment: Really good idea haven't tought of this :)

Comment: You can do `OPTIONS = {"U": str.upper, ...}` directly. Also `optional = OPTIONS.get(optional, lambda x: x)` might be a better fall-back than `None` which will then raise an error because `None` is not callable.

Comment: @Graipher Ahh yes `lambda x: x` I was looking for that :) I also added the `str.upper` but is was more to show you could supply your own function